# How can I manage combat difficulty in the Fall of Plaguestone adventure module?

Tags: combat, pathfinder-2e

I'm new to Pathfinder and started it with my group on roll20 due to Corona. I have decade long GM experience in in games like DSA (Das Schwarze Auge) and Shadowrun, but not for Dungeon Crawlers.

Long story short: We are playing the Fall of Plaguestone module and my group (Rogue, Wizard, Paladin and Cleric) needed hard intervention from my part as not to die on multiple encounters. Since I still need to get a feel for the difficulty I'm not changing anything from the module and play it by the letter.

The group nearly died by: (contains spoilers)

> The bear guarding the medicine bushes in Plaguestone, the wolves in the tree-root-cave (no ranged attacks possible), the battle against the animals & minders at the pen (because of unlucky dice) and the fight against the blood-slime.

Enemies are totally able to one-hit my players with a critical hit and I feel the only reason they survive at all are the mighty resurrection possibilities of the cleric (the 3 action heal). I'm looking for advice how to make the adventure more fun by not obviously saving my group, but also for other opinions on how difficult that module is.

The cleric and the paladin are level 2, the others level 1. The others will level up after the next encounter as there is only a small XP difference.

Cleric AC 17, HP 24
Paladin AC 18, HP 32
Rogue AC 18, HP 18
Wizard AC 18, HP 12

I feel like the group struggles as a whole, but the rogue is the weakest member in battle. The last fight (against the blood slime) was a total loss that had nothing to do with crits. In other fights I would say the crits are the problem but I'm not saying the dice are against my players.

Comment: The priest and the paladin are lvl 2, the others lvl 1. I feel like the group struggles as a whole but the rogue is the weakest member in battle. The last fight (against the blood slime) was a total loss that had nothing to do with crits, in other fights I would say the crits are the problem but I'm not saying the dice are against my players.

Comment: I played with them the free mini-module on roll20 and after it two decided to build new chars. The others will level up after the next encounter as there is only a small XP-difference.

Comment: How did the difference in XP happen? The game explicitly says that the group should be on the same level if you don't make any adjustments to the difficulty.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. The party is fighting and winning mostly, that seems good to me. What would you like to happen?

Comment: I get feedback from my group that they feel like I spare them from dying instead of they managing to win, which was true for at least two fights plus me letting enemies not attack too efficiently. I was hoping for either a hint how you manage the difficulty when playing a module or hopefully someone playing the same module telling me it is easy / hard for them so I get a better understanding. It is also probable that I gm it in some way incorrectly but I think it is hard to pinpoint that without me knowing what exactly could be responsible.

Comment: side note: how does a lv2 paladin and a lv1 sorcerer have the same AC? AC18 seems low for the champion and high for the sorcerer.

Comment: @Szega sorry, sorcerer was a translation error by me, it is a mage (or wizard?) actually. He has Dex 3 and the magic armour spell. The paladin is the prebuild Seelah (http://www.pathfindercommunity.net/iconic-characters/seelah---iconic-paladin/seelah-iconic-paladin-1).

Comment: My bad, I used the version already available in the PF2 demo-module in roll20 screenshot of the char here: https://ibb.co/56GzNV4

Comment: I just found a sheet listing all XP available in the module and realised that my whole group should be lvl 2 at our current part. I missed that creatures also give XP which is not listed in the module book. For others interested, here is the sheet: https://paizo.com/products/btq01zoh/discuss&page=3?Pathfinder-Adventure-The-Fall-of-Plaguestone#110

Comment: Ah, yes, I was confused by that at first, too. Challenges don't show their XP amount, just their level, and the XP depends on the level now. Feel free to write that as an answer, even if it's to your own question :)

Comment: Note that Fall of Plaguestone is harder than average - the number of severe encounters is high. Even on Paizo forums, where you would expect experienced players it is recognised as being harder than most adventures. This is probably partly due to it being written while they were still developing PF2, but also the author, Jason Bulmahn is known for writing harder than average scenarios.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After following the comments and re-reading the GM part in the rule book and running the adventure multiple times I identified the following mayor problems:

1. The game module "Fall of Plaguestone" doesn't list all the XP due, only bonus XP for certain objectives. To keep the group on the expected level for encounters it is necessary to award the group for overcoming adversaries and hazards ([Core Rulebook pg. 507](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=572)). Andrew Mullen created [a handy spreadsheet](https://paizo.com/products/btq01zoh/discuss&page=3?Pathfinder-Adventure-The-Fall-of-Plaguestone#110) listing all XP the group would earn in this module. Had I done so, my group would have had a higher level making fights more balanced.
2. Pathfinder 2e is heavily based on hero points to subsidize role play and to make fights more interesting, while also using them to make player characters more hero-like. The rule book specifies that the group should start each gaming session with one hero point and earn approximately one more each hour played. ([Core Rulebook pg. 507](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=572)) Adjusting this number especially before encounters you are not sure your group can handle can help balance it out.
3. As @Isaac mentioned the Fall of Plaguestone is more challenging than other adventures. On my second run with a different group I started to give the players more loot and also gave them more opportunities to notice danger before it came to a fight so they could go in with better positioning / preparations.

As a helpful source for GMs that may struggle with this as well, there is a live-play podcast available from ["Roll For Combat"](http://rollforcombat.com/tag/the-fall-of-plaguestone/) that plays the whole module, giving you a feeling how challenging each encounter will be and what you could do wrong, please note that the podcast was played when PF2 just came out and they sometimes interpret the rules incorrectly.

Comment: Also, there's a general expectation that the players enter combats (especially Severe combats!) with full health or near full health. Severe combats also expect players to have most of their resources (e.g. spells). A lot of players from other systems aren't used to this (especially the healing); your party should be taking time between encounters to top off on HP, which should be fairly trivial with your Paladin's Lay on Hands.

Comment: Point 2 is slightly inaccurate. Hero Points are "expected" to be given out about once per hour *total*, not per character. I personally find that to be a bit stingy and try to give them out such that each player has opportunities for about two bonus points per session of 4-5 hours.

Comment: [Reference](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=573) "In a typical game, you’ll hand out about 1 Hero Point during each hour of play after the first (for example, 3 extra points in a 4-hour session). If you want a more over-the-top game, or if your group is up against incredible odds and showing immense bravery, you might give them out at a faster rate, like 1 every 30 minutes (6 over a 4-hour session). Try to ensure each PC has opportunities to earn Hero Points, and avoid granting all of the Hero Points to a single character."